# Examples of finitely generated elementary amenable groups which are not virtually solvable

Tags: gr.group-theory

What are some examples of finitely generated (finitely presented) elementary amenable groups which are not virtually solvable?

Comment: Take the group of permutations with finite support of $\mathbb{Z}$: this group is non-virtually solvable, and locally finite (hence elementary amenable); of course it is not finitely generated. To make it f.g., take the semi-direct product by $\mathbb{Z}$ acting by conjugation by the shift.

Comment: Houghton groups are analogues of these, but are in addition finitely presented.

Comment: Apparently, the question on whether there exists a finitely presented elementary amenable group which is not virtually solvable appears in Kourovka notebook (asked by Linnell-Schick). Linnell mentioned it to me last summer and I also immediately thought of Houghton groups (as I had just read the paper by Brown  
http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/scan/1987.0044.0045.pdf
where their finite presentability was established). 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Houghton groups are (non-split) extensions of the group of the finitely supported permutations of the integers by $\mathbf{Z}^d$ for $d\ge 2$ and are thus elementary amenable and not virtually solvable. They're finitely presented, as shown by K.Brown [here](http://math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/scan/1987.0044.0045.pdf) (*Finiteness properties of groups*, JPAA 1987). They were introduced by Houghton as f.g. groups with coset spaces with $2<n<\infty$ ends.